# Regex to match multiple string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to parse a log file to retrieve the `time`, `type` and the `message`. A log file is constructed like this:

```
[08:52:18] [ERROR] Ceci doit aparaitre 
[08:52:18] [WARN] Bonjour
```

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
var result = Regex.Match(fileLogs, @"/\[(.+)\] \[(.+)\] (.+)/g");
```

Which is working fine on website like [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) but not on my code. I don't really understand why.

I want to retrieve these element to create a new instance of `Log` (which have just 3 attributes: `time`, `type` and `message`)

Comment: `but not on my code` => that's where we need more informations

Comment: What is `fileLogs`? Array of lines, a single line or what?

Comment: fileLogs is just a string containing the example text above. Result is the whole line.

Comment: Okay then see xanatos answer. Be careful, if you want to read the whole Log-File at ones, you need to use `Regex.Matches` else you'll just get the first appearence

Comment: for me `string fileLogs = "[08:52:18] [ERROR] Ceci doit aparaitre";
            var result = Regex.Match(fileLogs, @"\[(.+)\] \[(.+)\] (.+)");` works just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the initial `/` and the final `/g`. You are programming in C#, not Javascript.

```
var result = Regex.Match(fileLogs, @"\[(.+)\] \[(.+)\] (.+)");
```

Ideone showing that now it works: https://ideone.com/QkTYwS

To split it correctly you can use something like:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(fileLogs, @"\[(.+)\] \[(.+)\] (.+)");

foreach (Match match in result)
{
    string time = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string type = match.Groups[2].Value;
    string messsage = match.Groups[3].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}", time, type, messsage);
}
```

Note the use of the `Regex.Matches`.

Ideone: https://ideone.com/lUxnSs

Comment: Tried it too, but result.Value is the whole line.

Comment: @Sakuto *Which is working fine on website like RegexStorm but not on my code* Then it doesn't work fine with RegexStorm :-)

Comment: Thanks, figured it out while you were writing it, thanks (: The /, /g was for testing purpose, it was not on my initial code but I had problem dealing with the Groups attribute.